# Possible to add numpy arrays to python sets?

Tags: python, numpy, casting, set, tuples

I know that in order to add an element to a set it must be hashable, and numpy arrays seemingly are not. This is causing me some problems because I have the following bit of code:

```
fill_set = set()
for i in list_of_np_1D:
    vecs = i + np_2D
    for j in range(N):
        tup = tuple(vecs[j,:])
        fill_set.add(tup)

# list_of_np_1D is a list of 1D numpy arrays
# np_2D is a 2D numpy array
# np_2D could also be converted to a list of 1D arrays if it helped.
```

I need to get this running faster and nearly 50% of the run-time is spent converting slices of the 2D numpy array to tuples so they can be added to the set.

so I've been trying to find out the following

- Is there any way to make numpy arrays, or something that functions like numpy arrays (has vector addition) hashable so they can be added to sets?
- If not, is there a way I can speed up the process of making the tuple conversion?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not only are NumPy arrays not hashable, they're not even really *equatable*. `a == b` doesn't produce a boolean representing whether `a` equals `b` if either of `a` or `b` is an array, and `set` has no idea what to do with an array of elementwise comparison results or how to call `np.array_equal`.

Comment: Do you really need to convert your arrays to Python sets? Numpy natively supports various set operations on arrays (see [`numpy.lib.arraysetops`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.set.html)).

Comment: @ali_m I wasn't aware of that thanks, I'll go check it out now. Ultimately I have a two large collections of 1D arrays of integers, I need to be able to add more arrays to those collections and do something equivalent to the `.difference_update` operation that sets have.

Comment: You can use `tuple(vecs[j,:].tolist())` to reduce the convert time. You can even convert the array to a bytes object by `vecs[j, :].tobytes()` if you only want to save the array in a set.

Comment: @HYRY thanks man I'll go try those out now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create some data first:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
list_of_np_1D = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(500, 6))
np_2D = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(20, 6))
```

run your code:

```
%%time
fill_set = set()
for i in list_of_np_1D:
    vecs = i + np_2D
    for v in vecs:
        tup = tuple(v)
        fill_set.add(tup)
res1 = np.array(list(fill_set))
```

output:

```
CPU times: user 161 ms, sys: 2 ms, total: 163 ms
Wall time: 167 ms
```

Here is a speedup version, it use broadcast, `.view()` method to convert dtype to string, after calling `set()` convert the string back to array:

```
%%time
r = list_of_np_1D[:, None, :] + np_2D[None, :, :]
stype = "S%d" % (r.itemsize * np_2D.shape[1])
fill_set2 = set(r.ravel().view(stype).tolist())
res2 = np.zeros(len(fill_set2), dtype=stype)
res2[:] = list(fill_set2)
res2 = res2.view(r.dtype).reshape(-1, np_2D.shape[1])
```

output:

```
CPU times: user 13 ms, sys: 1 ms, total: 14 ms
Wall time: 14.6 ms
```

To check the result:

```
np.all(res1[np.lexsort(res1.T), :] == res2[np.lexsort(res2.T), :])
```

You can also use `lexsort()` to remove duplicated data:

```
%%time
r = list_of_np_1D[:, None, :] + np_2D[None, :, :]
r = r.reshape(-1, r.shape[-1])

r = r[np.lexsort(r.T)]
idx = np.where(np.all(np.diff(r, axis=0) == 0, axis=1))[0] + 1
res3 = np.delete(r, idx, axis=0)
```

output:

```
CPU times: user 13 ms, sys: 3 ms, total: 16 ms
Wall time: 16.1 ms
```

To check the result:

```
np.all(res1[np.lexsort(res1.T), :] == res3)
```